# Why Web Api add extra $id to result set

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have Web Api service that return enumerable list of some object,
but i see in client side some extra $id for each object ?
why I am getting it  ? What is the reason ? is is possible to deactivate it ?

Comment: We can *guess*, but it would be a lot easier to diagnose the problem if you show the code that's building/returning the list, the structure of the object, and the client-side result (and indicate which value in that result is the offending value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is automatically added handle so if the element appear again in the code it will just add a reference to it.

You can deactivate it by adding this to the Application_Start in the global asax (or any other bootstraper you are using)

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
```

Answer (score 1):

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;

Answer (score 1):

For .Net Core (for ex: .Net 6)
Add the below line of code in program.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the below for .Net Core 6

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
      x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
}
```